# Google TV VideoView 'Failed to Play'

Tags: google-tv

I'm trying to play a video in a VideoView on a Sony GTV (Android 3.2) and when the VideoView loads I get a 'Failed to Play' dialog. The output of ffmpeg -i on my video is:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'vz569287a41cd749cd8c0692a64d94453c.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    encoder         : Lavf53.4.0
  Duration: 00:00:21.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1166 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 576x432 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1070 kb/s, 23.99 fps, 23.95 tbr, 479 tbn, 47.90 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 91 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    :
```

According to: https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_media_formats h264 baseline with aac audio should be supported but has limited B-frame support. Is there a way to determine that the baseline profile is the issue?

The video plays fine on tablets running ICS (I don't have a Honeycomb tablet to test on).

The video can be found at:
https://view.vzaar.com/933735/video

Logcat output (from Logitech Revue, Sony device was unavailable):

```
04-26 18:38:36.409: W/AVInfo(1669): av_open_input_file https://view.vzaar.com/933735/video failed -2
04-26 18:38:36.409: I/MediaPlayerService(1669): getPlayerTypeFromProbe: https://view.vzaar.com/933735/video choose player type 0

04-26 18:40:45.325: I/AudioService(193):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@67001460com.google.tv.player.PlayerActivity$7@66c75718
04-26 18:40:45.373: D/MediaPlayer(21235): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
04-26 18:40:45.373: I/HDMIPassthru(1669): Creating pure ISMD based HDMIPassthruPlayer for Sodaville platform
04-26 18:40:45.373: V/GoogleTVMediaApi(1669): ui_plane_match: 1, display_mode_size_match: 0, tgtW = 1280, tgtH = 720
04-26 18:40:45.373: V/GoogleTVMediaApi(1669): Update Video Params
04-26 18:40:45.373: V/GoogleTVMediaApi(1669): Ideal      : 1204x672 @ (38, 24)
04-26 18:40:45.373: V/GoogleTVMediaApi(1669): Ideal Crop : 0x0 @ (0, 0)
04-26 18:40:45.373: V/GoogleTVMediaApi(1669): Scale      : 1280x720
04-26 18:40:45.373: V/GoogleTVMediaApi(1669): Crop       : 1280x720 @ (0, 0)
04-26 18:40:45.373: V/GoogleTVMediaApi(1669): Src        : 1280x720 @ (0, 0)
04-26 18:40:45.373: V/GoogleTVMediaApi(1669): Dst        : 1280x720 @ (0, 0)
04-26 18:40:45.373: D/HDMIPassthru(1669): Create ISMD_HDMIPassthruPlayer
04-26 18:40:45.377: I/HDMIPassthru(1669): Got init display mode 1280x720p@59.939999   M
04-26 18:40:45.377: I/HDMIPassthru(1669): Set data source: hdmi://localhost?port=2
04-26 18:40:45.385: D/HDMIPassthru(1669): ISMD_HDMIPassthruPlayer prepareAsync (port=2 ignored, no input port control library detected)
04-26 18:40:45.405: D/MediaPlayer(21235): getMetadata
04-26 18:40:45.405: E/MediaPlayerService(1669): getMetadata failed -38
04-26 18:40:45.409: I/AudioService(193):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@67001460com.google.tv.player.PlayerActivity$7@66c75718
04-26 18:40:45.409: D/HDMIPassthru(1669): virtual android::status_t fishtank::ISMD_HDMIPassthruPlayer::setVolume(float, float) 1.000000 1.000000
04-26 18:40:45.409: D/HDMIPassthru(1669): android::status_t fishtank::ISMD_HDMIPassthruPlayer::applyVolume() 0
04-26 18:40:45.409: W/HDMIPassthru(1669): Failed to get dev handle for setOutputVolume.
04-26 18:40:45.409: D/HDMIPassthru(1669): ISMD_HDMIPassthruPlayer start
04-26 18:40:45.409: D/GtvResourceManager(137): Allocate resource holder for context 546063a61f 0x9485718 124
04-26 18:40:45.409: D/GtvResourceManager(137): Allocate resource holder for context 546063a61f 0x9487fc0 125
04-26 18:40:45.409: D/IsmdResourceManager(137): resource update 0 for 4 1 0x9485718
04-26 18:40:45.413: D/HDMIPassthru(1669): Action 0 for device type 4 index 1
04-26 18:40:45.417: D/IsmdResourceManager(137): resource update 0 for 1 0 0x9485718
04-26 18:40:45.417: D/HDMIPassthru(1669): Action 0 for device type 1 index 0
04-26 18:40:45.417: D/IsmdResourceManager(137): resource update 0 for 3 1 0x9485718
04-26 18:40:45.417: D/HDMIPassthru(1669): Action 0 for device type 3 index 1
04-26 18:40:45.417: D/IsmdResourceManager(137): resource update 0 for 0 4 0x9485718
04-26 18:40:45.417: D/HDMIPassthru(1669): Action 0 for device type 0 index 0
04-26 18:40:45.417: I/HDMIPassthru(1669): ISMD Passthru player was assigned plane 4
04-26 18:40:45.449: D/HDMIPassthru(1669): android::status_t fishtank::ISMD_HDMIPassthruPlayer::applyVolume() 0
04-26 18:40:45.449: D/HDMIPassthru(1669): virtual android::status_t fishtank::ISMD_HDMIPassthruPlayer::setVolume(float, float) 1.000000 1.000000
04-26 18:40:45.449: D/HDMIPassthru(1669): android::status_t fishtank::ISMD_HDMIPassthruPlayer::applyVolume() 0
04-26 18:40:45.449: I/AudioService(193):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@67001460com.google.tv.player.PlayerActivity$7@66c75718
04-26 18:40:45.449: D/HDMIPassthru(1669): virtual android::status_t fishtank::ISMD_HDMIPassthruPlayer::setVolume(float, float) 1.000000 1.000000
04-26 18:40:45.449: D/HDMIPassthru(1669): android::status_t fishtank::ISMD_HDMIPassthruPlayer::applyVolume() 0
04-26 18:40:45.489: I/HDMIPassthru(1669): IsVideoModeChangeNeeded, no change needed, staying in mode 1280x720p@59.94M
04-26 18:40:45.513: I/HDMIPassthru(1669): Audio Mode Change: 0 format 0 channel 0 Hz (0/0) 0 bits/sample.  Signal absent
04-26 18:40:45.513: I/HDMIPassthru(1669): Audio Input: Muted
04-26 18:40:45.513: W/HDMIPassthru(1669): Invalid audio mode received for dev 32. (ismd_res = 0) ss 0 fs 0
04-26 18:40:45.513: I/HDMIPassthru(1669): Audio Input: Un-Muted
04-26 18:40:45.513: I/HDMIPassthru(1669): HDCP status = disabled.
04-26 18:40:45.513: I/HDMIPassthru(1669): handleVideoMute: video not muted
04-26 18:40:45.513: E/HDMIPassthru(1669): HDMI Passthru: Video Renderer Error Event Received
04-26 18:40:45.525: D/MediaDevicesService(282): Media devices in use (acquisition - Logitech01@com.logitech.harmony)
04-26 18:40:45.525: D/MediaDevicesService(282):  - Logitech01@com.logitech.harmony
04-26 18:40:45.537: D/DeviceAcquisitionService(333): ON_BIND: (DeviceId) - Logitech01
```

I don't have the Sony devices at the moment to test on so pulled this logcat from a Logitech Revue. Strangely an even worse issue has occurred here as the when setting the video URI the Revue just displays a black screen and any keyboard input results in an ANR.

My code to start the video looks like:

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(getSlideActivity());
    mc.setAnchorView(mVideo);
    mVideo.setMediaController(mc);
    mVideo.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://view.vzaar.com/933735/video"));
    mVideo.start();
}
```

I modified the video playing code to be within an AsyncTask and it no longer crashes on the Revue (though video doesn't play):

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Looper.prepare();   
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(getSlideActivity());
        mc.setAnchorView(mVideo);
        mVideo.setMediaController(mc);
        mVideo.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(mSlide.getMedia()));
        Looper.loop();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        mVideo.start();
    }
}.execute();
```

After adding some logging statements to the AsyncTask above I see it never gets past the line that calls 'setVideoURI'.

Comment: Please provide the video url and logcat output.

Comment: I've added the video url (https://view.vzaar.com/933735/video) and logcat output to the question.

Comment: If your video had an extension, what would it be?  Try adding it to the url.  (I replicated your issue on one of my boxes).

Comment: .mp4 - I've uploaded the video to my GDrive:
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1ovPL3lXBmXNDdrWXJPNXc3MnM

I'll test it with a direct link to the .mp4

Comment: A ha! A direct link to the .mp4 works. Strange how this works fine on the tablet without that style of link. Should I add this to the Google TV issue tracker?

Comment: sure. please add it to the Google TV issue tracker.

Comment: please add what you found as a answer to this question, so that its easier to find for someone else who comes across the same issue.

Comment: @MeghaJoshi-GoogleTVDevRel I really am not sure why the one link worked on other Android devices but not on Google TV, so I hesitate to put something down as an answer here without that bit of information. I assume it has something to do with VideoView on GTV not handling redirects well?

Comment: The reason for the problem is that the media players are very different internally on a Google TV and a normal android device.  Adding the suffix is the right solution for a Google TV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VideoView on Google TV is different than on standard Android therefore the URI needs to be directly to the file, per Les Vogel (Google TV DevRel).